Azure Databricks and Trace Telemetry Data
All,
We are in the process of strategizing on an Observability Platform for our data landscape which includes Datalake, Data Factory, Tidal and Azure Databricks to capture Telemetry data (Metrics, Logs and Traces)
I can see the Metrics and Logs tab for each of the cluster but I don't see anything for Traces. I'm aware that the Application Instrumentation needs to be handled inside the Pyspark code within the notebook.
Does that mean that the Azure Databricks itself does not generate any Trace data by itself?
Thanks,
grajee

You can enable verbose log, which include the text of the query (among other things) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/admin/account-settings/verbose-logs

It does not trace itself. To log traces you need to use Application Instrumentation inside the code of notebook.  I do agree with @Chen Hirsh that you can enable verbose logs. Firstly set diagnostic settings to log analytics workspace.
Click on Admin settings and then advanced settings and then enable it like below:

Then executed like below:

After sometime i have checked logs in workspace using DatabricksNotebook:

Also refer my  answer in SO-thread.
